# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-7, windows-7-x64

I have developed a project on codeigniter a phpframework. It's working perfectly on my localhost where xampp is running. But right now the client want it on IIS windows server. I have uploaded my whole project in the "wwwroot" folder and I can only get my opening page. But when I try to click on any link I get:

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**.

Here is my problem link to show image
http://www.flickr.com/photos/118792012@N04/12790173834/

Here is my server configuration:

```
 server: IIS7
    O/S: Windows7-64bit
```

## Environment: Runing on my own laptop

Update:
      Here is my htaccess file configuration-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /mobile_masala/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Code igniter usually has index.php in URL. It is not visible in your link. If you have added any htaccess, share it as well.

Comment: i share my htaccess file. Please see my updated questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try this http://codefury.net/2011/01/codeigniter-php-iis-mysql-mssql/ or search google https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+php+response+lag. Hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open your IIS management console at C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc.
Drill down to your web site, right-click and select Properties.
Select the Home Directory tab, then click on the Configuration button.
Select the Mappings tab. If you don’t see a .php extension listed, click the Add button. Browse to the PHP 5 DLL (which may be at C:\Program Files\PHP\php5isapi.dll). Type .php into the Extension field and leave everything else at the default values. Click OK. The extension and executable path will be filled out and under Verbs you should see “All”

Comment: how to find Drill down to your web site, right-click and select Properties?